# Testing async method using React testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have button in component:

```
<button
    type="button"
    title="Logout"
    data-testid="logout"
    onClick={logout}
>
```

and method `logout`:

```
const logout = async () => {
    try {
        await authLogout()
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    } finally {
        props.history.push('/login')
    }
}
```

Now I trying testing logout method by click on button:

```
describe('UserMenuComponent', () => {
  it('go to login page after click on logout', async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory()

    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <UserMenuComponent />,
      </Router>,
      {
        initialState: { reducersAuth: initialState },
      },
    )

    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('logout'))
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/login')
  })
})
```

Inside method `logout` in `finally` block I have `props.history.push('/login')` and I check this in my test: `expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/login')` but test return error:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "/login"
Received: "/"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [useHistory()](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook to get history object inside your SFC.

Besides, since the `logout` function is an async function, you should use [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor) method to wait for your expectations to pass.

E.g.

`UserMenuComponent.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

async function authLogout() {}

export function UserMenuComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const logout = async () => {
    try {
      await authLogout();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      history.push('/login');
    }
  };

  return <button type="button" title="Logout" data-testid="logout" onClick={logout}></button>;
}
```

`UserMenuComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import { fireEvent, render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { UserMenuComponent } from './UserMenuComponent';

describe('UserMenuComponent', () => {
  it('go to login page after click on logout', async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(history, 'push');

    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <UserMenuComponent />,
      </Router>
    );

    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('logout'));
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(pushSpy).toBeCalledWith('/login');
      expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/login');
    });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66571376/UserMenuComponent.test.tsx
  UserMenuComponent
    ✓ go to login page after click on logout (82 ms)

-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                   | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files              |   91.67 |      100 |     100 |   90.91 |                   
 UserMenuComponent.tsx |   91.67 |      100 |     100 |   90.91 | 12                
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.881 s, estimated 4 s
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) to wait for your expectation to pass.

```js
await waitFor(() => expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/login'))
```